# Rails 4: unable to view the show page in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My restaurant review app works in Localhost but when i try this on heroku and click on the link to show the reviews i get We're sorry, but something went wrong. heroku logs shows the following information with the error **ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass):**

```
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175203+00:00 app[web.1]:     46:                <h4>
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175221+00:00 app[web.1]:     49:                <p><%= review.created_at.strftime("%-m/%-d/%y") %></p>
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175223+00:00 app[web.1]:     50:                </td>
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175225+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/restaurants/show.html.erb:47:in `block in _app_views_restaurants_show_html_erb__3540437068917616550_70094864076860'
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175226+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/restaurants/show.html.erb:43:in `_app_views_restaurants_show_html_erb__3540437068917616550_70094864076860'
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175303+00:00 app[web.1]:     48:                </h4>
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175229+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175284+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass):
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175307+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/restaurants/show.h
tml.erb:47:in `block in _app_views_restaurants_show_html_erb__3540437068917616550_70094864076860'
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175298+00:00 app[web.1]:     45:                <td>
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175199+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass):
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175282+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175304+00:00 app[web.1]:     49:                <p><%= review.created_at.strftime("%-m/%-d/%y") %></p>
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175309+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/restaurants/show.html.erb:43:in `_app_views_restaurants_show_html_erb__3540437068917616550_70094864076860'
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175300+00:00 app[web.1]:     46:                <h4>
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175218+00:00 app[web.1]:     47:                <%= "#{review.user.first_name.capitalize} #{review.user.last_name.capitalize[0]}." %>
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175301+00:00 app[web.1]:     47:                <%= "#{review.user.first_name.capitalize} #{review.user.last_name.capitalize[0]}." %>
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175310+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175305+00:00 app[web.1]:     50:                </td>
2014-08-20T09:32:49.175312+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-20T09:32:49.626763+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/restaurants/5" host=yelpdemo2014.herokuapp.com request_id=76387447-eb34-431b-9fcf-785a901e95ee fwd="185.30.24.132" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=58ms status=500 bytes=1030
2014-08-20T09:32:49.580600+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
2014-08-20T09:32:49.580595+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
2014-08-20T09:32:49.617957+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered restaurants/show.html.erb within layouts/application (20.7ms)
2014-08-20T09:32:49.617970+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered restaurants/show.html.erb within layouts/application (20.7ms)
2014-08-20T09:32:49.620207+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 37ms
2014-08-20T09:32:49.622252+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass):
2014-08-20T09:32:49.580536+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by RestaurantsController#show as HTML
2014-08-20T09:32:49.620214+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 37ms
2014-0
```

show.html

```
div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= image_tag @restaurant.image_url %>

<h2>
  <%= @restaurant.name %>
</h2>

<div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= @avg_rating %> ></div>
<p><%= "#{@reviews.length} reviews" %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Address:</strong>
  <%= @restaurant.address %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Phone:</strong>
  <%= @restaurant.phone %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Website:</strong>
  <%= link_to @restaurant.website, @restaurant.website %>
</p>

    <%= link_to 'Write a review', new_restaurant_review_path(@restaurant), class: "btn btn-primary" %>

</div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <% if @reviews.blank? %>
            <h3>No reviews yet, be the first to write one!</h3>
        <% else %>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-3"></th>
                        <th class="col-md-9"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>
                                <%= "#{review.user.first_name.capitalize} #{review.user.last_name.capitalize[0]}." %>
                            </h4>
                            <p><%= review.created_at.strftime("%-m/%-d/%y") %></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= review.rating %> ></div>
                            <p><%= h(review.comment).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').html_safe %></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_restaurant_path(@restaurant), class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', restaurants_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>

<script>
    $('.star-rating').raty({
        path: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yelpdemoneil/stars',
        readOnly: true,
        score: function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-score');
  }
});
</script>
```

restaurant controller

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_restaurant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /restaurants
  # GET /restaurants.json
  def index
    @restaurants = Restaurant.all
  end

  # GET /restaurants/1
  # GET /restaurants/1.json
  def show
    @reviews = Review.where(restaurant_id: @restaurant.id).order("created_at DESC")
    if @reviews.blank?
      @avg_rating = 0
    else
      @avg_rating = @reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
    end
  end

  # GET /restaurants/new
  def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new
  end

  # GET /restaurants/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /restaurants
  # POST /restaurants.json
  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @restaurant.save
        format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @restaurant }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /restaurants/1
  # PATCH/PUT /restaurants/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @restaurant.update(restaurant_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /restaurants/1
  # DELETE /restaurants/1.json
  def destroy
    @restaurant.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to restaurants_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_restaurant
      @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def restaurant_params
      params.require(:restaurant).permit(:name, :address, :phone, :website, :image)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nil**

The error is here:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass)
```

The problem is that you're calling a method on a `variable` / `object` which isn't set. As you mention it's only showing on Heroku, I'd say that it's caused by you not having the required records in your database

The fix for this is rather simple:

```
<% if @reviews.any? %>
   <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
      ...
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Data**

The bottom line is that you need to have data in your database in order to populate the various variables / objects you wish to display in your application

The problem for a lot of people is that Heroku doesn't maintain the same database as the your local system, hence if you expect data to be there, and there isn't, your system will invoke the exception you're seeing

The bottom line is that you'll either need some validation (to determine if the data you require is present), or you'll need to [seed your production database](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html) with the required records for your application

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain your solution in detail , cheers Neil

Comment: As a bit of an aside, when iterating (or doing anything with) arrays that you suspect might have nils, empty strings, etc, in them, you can ignore the blank values with `my_array.reject(&:blank?)`.  In this case this wouldn't try to iterate on the values of @reviews that were equal to `nil`, and if there were no non-blank values in `@reviews` then it wouldn't iterate at all.

Comment: Also, `my_array.reject!(&:blank?)` (note the !) will permanently remove the blank values from the array.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Rich and here is an alternative workaround:

I use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) for optional attributes like "first name" because i don't want to force users through validations to submit them:

```
<%= "#{review.user.first_name.try(:capitalize)} #{review.user.last_name.try(:capitalize)}." %>
```

This way it shouldn't throw exceptions weather there was an attribute or not